# How to find the person details in Quora by their email id?

Tags: java, quora

I found a way to get login user data [From Quora API](http://api.quora.com/api/logged_in_user?fields=inbox,notifs). But I want to get profiles by the users' email id only. How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not supported**

Even the currently allowed features are only of the **logged in** user. So there are no ways to fetch the user profile by their id.

Quora API is still in its alpha phase and only a handful of basic fields are permited as of now. It doesn't seem to be their high priority.

Currently allowed fields are `inbox`, `followers`, `following`, and `notifs`.

Note that `followers`, and `following` return the count, not the users.

From the post regarding this on [Quora Extension API](https://www.quora.com/profile/Edmond-Lau/Edmond-Laus-Posts/Quora-Extension-API).

> To request particular fields about the currently logged in user, add a
>   fields query parameter with a comma-separated listed of desired
>   fields.  Currently supported fields include inbox, followers,
>   following, and notifs.  For example, to request inbox and
>   notifications data, go to:

Although the link is quite old, seems like no much progress has been made in that respect.